# Access list of Podcasts and Episodes (MLMediaSourceType?) on device

Tags: ios, podcast, media-library

Is there a way to get a list of Podcasts and Episodes on an iOS device?  I am looking in the API documentation and it seems like MLMediaSourceType would be what I need.  Or within the MLMediaLibrary class.

I want a way to display a simple list of Podcasts and episodes that are downloaded locally on an iOS device within an app.

Thanks in advance!